# Unable to configure Confluence Publish plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I want to upload attachments to a page in Confluence in a post build action using a pipeline job.

I downloaded the Confluence Publisher plugin. Im trying to use my email id as username and API Token as password to test login. (tried with both http and https)
Keeps giving Authentication Error (401)

I tried from postman with same token and username (Auth method as API Authentication). Works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here with version 0.12.0.
Problem is fixed for me with changing to version 0.17.1